# Angular Directive in ng-repeat get current clicked item $scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have created a directive with a date picker inside of it called calendar. The actual date picker javascript has been created in JQuery and for me to be able to set the ng-model I have found the following code which works:

```
var clickedID = "#" + $scope.indexid + "_datePicker";
$(clickedID).trigger('input');
```

The problem is $scope.indexid is always showing as the last value in the array of calendar directives.

To clarify for example the directive shows my variables as the following:

```
[
  { indexid: 1},
  { indexid: 2},
  { indexid: 3}
]
```

When any the calendar is clicked on in the page $scope.indexid will always return 3 (the last item in the array). How would I fix this problem?

It is a very difficult problem to explain. If you would like any more information please let me know. I will try to add as much as requested.

EDIT more code:

```
//Index Page

<div ng-repeat="item in items">

 <calendar indexid="{{$index}}"></calendar>

</div>


//In the Directive
scope: {
  ngModel: "=",
  indexid: "@"
}

//In Directive Controller
console.log($scope.indexid);   

//In the directive template
<input type="text" ng-model="testModel" id="{{::indexid}}"/>
```

Comment: it looks like an issue with bad understanding of scopes and loops in javascript itself. Can you provide a greater piece of code?

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe Sure I will try to add as much as I am allowed.

Comment: I agree with @DeblatonJean-Philippe, and in addition this may be a problem with changing the data without triggering a $digest loop to let angular know something changed.

Comment: @AshleyCoolman it seems like I cant get the this.calendItem it instead references the last one created.

Comment: Hm, what happens when you change `id="{{::indexid}}` to `id="{{indexid}}` ?

Comment: As far as I can remember :: is used for one time binding which uses less resources? I have changed it to {{indexid}} and unfortunately nothing changes.

Comment: @MethodMan what about = `<calendar indexid="{{item.$index}}"></calendar>` ? ps : your understanding of one time binding is Ok, and this should not be a problem

Comment: @MethodMan : if previous comment is not a solution, can you provide the way you you create your array of variables (the `[{indexid:1}]`?

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe I do not create an array I simply use one <calendar> and many are created by the amount of items in another array. My problem has to do with selecting specific <calendar> items in an ng-repeat not with the above array. Its the array of calendar template items and getting their ID's that is the issue.

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe the reason I display the array in my question is because that is the output that the calendar items come back as.

Comment: @MethodMan: one observation that may be significant is that your directive scope is referencing ngModel,  but you have no ng-model attribute with the directive.

Answer (score 0):

When you loop over the array that you need to pass in each object by reference to be able to set values on it. You do this like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <calendar item="item"></calendar>
</div>
```

`item` will hold the current element in the array, so your index has to be called off of that.

In your directive, you can set it up like this:

```
scope: {
  item: "=" // reference to 'item' from the parent scope ... your loop
},
template: '<input type="text" ng-model="testModel" id="{{::item.indexid}}"/>',
link: function ($scope) {
  console.log($scope.item.indexid);

  console.log($scope.testModel); // this is the value of the input
}
```

This pattern should give you better access to each array item. By passing it in by reference you can write back to it; changes made to `item` inside the directive will be seen in the `items` array on the outer scope.